# Is definining scale-down-utilization-threshold on GKE possible?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Can you even define the scale-down-utilization-threshold on GKE?  I can't figure out where I would define this if it is actually possible.

Comment: Have you ever solved it? I can't for the life of me figure out how to get GKE to scale down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean scale down an [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) or scale down a [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) or scale down cluster nodes based on the [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler), or scale down GCP [instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) or an AWS [ASGs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

- A Kubernetes HPA supports it based on a metric (typically CPU utilization). It will scale down to a minimum number of replicas defined in the HPA Kubernetes resource.
- A Kubernetes VPA [supports it](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#is-cluster-autoscaler-compatible-with-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscalers) based on [requests/limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) (CPU, Memory). Keep in mind that it's not supported if used together with an HPA that is also using CPU and memory as scale metrics.
- The Kubernetes cluster autoscaler also supports downscaling based on the `--scale-down-utilization-threshold` and `--scan-interval` [options](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work). [It's not recommended](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#is-cluster-autoscaler-compatible-with-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscalers) to use this together with a GCP instance group or an AWS ASG.
- GCP Instance groups or AWS ASGs scale down is supported on the nodes provided that you are not using the cluster autoscaler and using CPU or other metrics specific to the cloud provider VM instances.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ahh, yes the cluster autoscaler.  The problem I am having is I have preemptible nodes with absolutely nothing on them except for kube-system pods and the cluster autoscaler won't remove them. They just site there, doing literally nothing.  At first I thought it was because my other nodes were above 50% requested resources, so I bumped the resource requests way way down.  Now there is about 80% free, and still after hours it won't remove the nodes.  It's just bizarre!

Comment: Are you using the latest cluster autoscaler and using the `--scale-down-utilization-threshold` option?

Comment: Where do I put that flag?

Comment: The cluster-autoscaler deployment. It must be somewhere in your cluster if you said you are running it.

Comment: Its running on GKE so I don't have direct access to that...I don't believe

Comment: I would open a support ticket with GKE